# TweenLite AS3 moving on x-axis issue

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, tween

I'm trying to create a simple animation effect with TweenLite AS3, having a movieclip ("selectedFrame"), shift on the x-axis on the stage every few seconds.  Other TweenLite effects (using the 'alpha' function) are working fine, but for some reason I can't get this simple shift to work.
Here is the block of code I'm trying to move the MC with:

```
 TweenLite.to(selectedFrame, 1, {x:501.6});
```

TweenLite.to(selectedFrame, 1, {x:536.8, delay:3, overwrite:1});
 TweenLite.to(selectedFrame, 1, {x:572.1, delay:6, overwrite:1});
 TweenLite.to(selectedFrame, 1, {x:607.5, delay:9, overwrite:1});
 TweenLite.to(selectedFrame, 1, {x:501.6, delay:12, overwrite:1});

(this is all located within a function that continuously loops based on another movieclip, and otherwise is working fine)

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the easing:

```
TweenLite.to(selectedFrame, 1, {x:501.6, ease:Strong.easeOut});
```